# R - barplot overlay with bars of different width

Tags: r, width, overlay, bar-chart

I am aware that similar questions have been asked, but non of the provided answers addressed my problem with superimposed barplots in R.

I would like to generate a barplot with two series of y-values, having the same x-values.

The second series of y-values represents a subset of the first series of y-values. Therefore I would like to plot first series 1 as barplot and then superimpose series 2.

What I would like to present an overlay of the y2-series with only half the bar size of y1-series (setting width = 0.5).
Unfortunately, this shifts all bars of the second series to the left.

I then can play around a creating a vector for spaces (`spaces = c(0.9, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4)`) but I cannot figure out to automatize it.

Could anybody suggest a clever solution to this ?

Thank you very much in advance,
Werner

```
# x-values
number_aa <-  c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
# y1-values
peptide_total <- c(62040, 57755, 50053, 45077, 39011)
# y2-values
peptide_unique <- c(56791, 54978, 47943, 43248, 37658)

# determine ymax (from y1-values)
ymax <- peptide_total[which.max(peptide_total)]
ymax

# determine xmax (from x-values)
xmax <- number_aa[which.max(number_aa)]
xmax

# assign vector of midpoint-values of first barplot (y1) to x 
x <- barplot(peptide_total, names.arg = number_aa,
         xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
         width = 1)

# set plotting to overlay (no new plot)
par(new = TRUE)

barplot(peptide_unique, col = 'black', names.arg=x,
    xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
    width = 0.5,
    axisnames = FALSE)

# ----> second bar plot is not aligned on first barplot
```

[image]

========================================================================

===> this was added after the response of @G5W

What I would like to see is the following, understanding the system for setting `width` and `space` options for the barplot.

Using the code below for barplot 2:

```
# creating second barplot
space_vector = c(0.9, rep(1.4, 4))

barplot(peptide_unique, col = 'black', names.arg=x,
    xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
    width = 0.5, space = space_vector,
    axisnames = FALSE)
```

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71I6T.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second barplot, increase the spacing.

```
barplot(peptide_unique, col = 'black', names.arg=x,
    xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
    width = 0.5, space=c(0.4,rep(1.4,4)),
    axisnames = FALSE)
```

[image: Spaced Barplot]

### Addendum based on clarification of question:

No matter how many bars you make,  if you stick with width=0.5 for the
second bar,  you can use `spacing = space=c(0.9,rep(1.4,length(number_aa)-1))`
to get the second bar in the center of the first one. (Make the first number
0.4 to get it on the left and 1.4 to get it on the right.)

You can compute that this should work. The documentation for barplot says:

> ### space
>
> the amount of space (as a fraction of the average bar width) left before each bar.

The first barplot used the defaults so `width = 1` and `space = 0.2`.
The first bar starts at 0.2.  The center will be at 0.2 + 0.5 = 0.7.
Each subsequent bar moves over by 1.2 (0.2 spacing + 1.0 for the width of the bar).

Since all of the bars for the second set have width 0.5, the average is also 0.5.
You want each bar of the second set to be centered on the bars from the first set.
If you use `spacing = 0.9` for the first bar, its left edge will be at
`spacing * bar_width = 0.9 * 0.5 = 0.45`. Moving to the center of the bar will add
0.5*0.5 = 0.25 so the center of the first bar will be at 0.7 which aligns
with the center of the first bar of the first set.  Since we are using
space = 1.4 for the rest of the bars in the second set, each bar will move
over by `spacing * bar_width + bar_width = 1.4*0.5 + 0.5 = 1.2` which agrees
with the amount that each bar in the first set moves over.

To confirm this calculation, you can just generate a lot of junk data sets
using different number of bars and confirm that they line up. Here is code
like yours, but the values have no real meaning, they are just illustrative.
Try changing the value of NumTypes = 10 to various values to convince yourself
that this is correct.

```
NumTypes = 11
number_aa <-  6:(5+NumTypes)
peptide_total  <- sort(rnorm(NumTypes, 51000,9000), decreasing=TRUE)
peptide_unique <- sort(rnorm(NumTypes, 47000,8000), decreasing=TRUE)

# determine ymax (from y1-values)
ymax <- peptide_total[which.max(peptide_total)]
ymax

xmax <- number_aa[which.max(number_aa)]
xmax

# assign vector of midpoint-values of first barplot (y1) to x 
x <- barplot(peptide_total, names.arg = number_aa,
         xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
         width = 1)

# set plotting to overlay (no new plot)
par(new = TRUE)

barplot(peptide_unique, col = 'black', names.arg=x,
    xlim = c(0, xmax), ylim = c(0, ymax),
    width = 0.5, space=c(0.9,rep(1.4,length(number_aa)-1)),
    axisnames = FALSE)
```

[image: Center bars]

Comment: Hi @G5W,
Thank you very much for your response.
As I wrote above I am aware of the  `(spaces = ...)` option.
However, for every change of width I have to perform then an trial and error series in order to align the second plot on the first plot.

My question:  Is there a way to calculate it (automatize it) or is the only way to try and test the behavior using `width =` and `spaces = `?

Comment: Thank you very much @G5W for your second detailed answer! 

Even I had read the documentation for barplot (maybe not "the" but "a" doc), I must have overseen the sentence you posted.
Now, this is very clear !!! And your information was what I needed.